# Cosets and Lagrange's theorom

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a finite group of order $n$ and $m$ is relatively prime to $n$. If $g$ exists in $G$ and $g^m = e$, prove that $g=e$.

I know that in a finite group a raised to the power order of $G$ is the identity. How do I finish this off?

Comment: "Lagrange" ....

Answer (score 7):

Suppose towards contradiction, assume that **g** isn't equal to **e**. This means **g^m=e** which implies  **|(g)|=k** for some **k > 1** that divides **m**. By La grange's theorem, we know that **k** divides **n**, so **gcd(m,n)=k**. This contradicts the statement of our question that **n,m** are relatively prime, so our assumption is false and **g=e**.

Answer (score 5):

You know that if $g^m =e$, then the order of $g$ divides $m$. But from Lagrange, the order of $g$ divides $n$ as well. What integer divides $m$ and $n$, if they are relatively prime?

Comment: the identity and the order of G

Comment: Since they're relatively prime, the only common divisor is $1$. What elements have order $1$?

Answer (score 3):

$$(n,m)=1\iff \exists\,x,y\in\Bbb Z\;\;s.t.\;\;nx+my=1\implies$$

$$g=g^1=g^{nx+my}=\left(g^x\right)^n\cdot\left(g^m\right)^y=1\cdot1=1$$

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use what you said. $g^m=e$, and by your second statement, $g^n=e$. Now by Bezout's lemma, there exist integers $x,y$ such that $mx+ny=1$. Then consider
$$
g=g^{mx+ny}=(g^m)^x(g^n)^y=e^xe^y=e
$$
So $g=e$.

One could also use a proof by contradiction- assume $g\neq e$ (so $m\neq 1$) and $g^m=e$. Then by Lagrange's theorem $m\mid n$, so $m$ and $n$ are not relatively prime, which is a contradiction.